# Why do I get different regression outputs in SAS and in Stata when using Prais-Winsten estimation?

Tags: sas, time-series, regression, stata

I have a time series dataset with serious serial correlation problem, so I adopted Prais-Winsten estimator with iterated estimates to fix that. I did the regressions in Stata with the following command:

```
prais depvar indepvar indepvar2, vce(robust) rhotype(regress)
```

My colleague wanted to reproduce my results in SAS, so she used the following:

```
proc autoreg data=DATA;
model depvar = indepvar indepvar2/nlag=1 iter itprint method=YW;
run;
```

For the different specifications we ran, some of them roughly match, while others do not. Also I noticed that for each regression specification, Stata has many more iterations than SAS. I wonder if there is something wrong with my (or my colleague's) code.

---

**Update**

Inspired by Joe's comment, I modified my SAS code.

```
/*Iterated Estimation*/
proc autoreg data=DATA;
model depvar = indepvar indepvar2/nlag=1 itprint method=ITYW;
run;

/*Twostep Estimation*/
proc autoreg data=DATA;
model depvar = indepvar indepvar2/nlag=1 itprint method=YW;
run;
```

Comment: It's not clear what the **programming** problem is here. You have code that runs in both cases. This is essentially a statistical question, namely are the results of these procedures expected to be identical and indeed if they differ, what is the reason? Without a reproducible example it's hard for anyone to comment. I'd raise this in Stata and SAS forums.  Note spellings Prais, Winsten, Stata (all edited in).

Comment: @NickCox I think there is somewhat of a programming problem, namely whether the Stata code is identical to the SAS code in how it works.  I'm not sure it will end up with a good answer here - neither Stata nor SAS have vast followings here, particularly on the statistician side - but who knows.  It may get a better answer on [stats.se], or on the various fora of the languages, but I think it's on-topic here also.

Comment: Shawn - values for method include `YW` and `ITYW` - I'd be curious what happens when you specify the latter.  It looks to me like it's possible they have opposing defaults - STATA provides option `twostep` to make only one iteration, while SAS provides `YW` vs `ITYW`.  But, I'm not familiar with this kind of estimate so I'm just guessing from the docs.  While you specify `iter`, that may be overridden by the `method` statement.

Comment: @joe I got the `iter` part from here:[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=8FppWLEFHU8C&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=prais+winsten+estimation+in+sas&source=bl&ots=b20xk7XLvr&sig=Uj5pv6UeTS_lvGeMUaTkYeLdIfM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBmoVChMI0Mi2kYiJyQIVRzI-Ch19ngLv#v=onepage&q=prais%20winsten%20estimation%20in%20sas&f=false). I modified the code based on your comment. The coefficients are still not exactly the same, but `YW` results match in general with `twostep` results, and `ITYW` matches in general with the iterated estimation in Stata. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a few suggestions. Note that I'm not a real statistician and am not familiar with the specific estimators here, so this is just a quick read of the docs.

First off, the most likely issue is that it looks like SAS uses the OLS variance estimation method.  That is, in your Stata code, you have `vce(robust)`, which is in contrast to what I read SAS as using, the equivalent of `vce(ols)`.  See [this page in the docs](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_autoreg_sect020.htm) which explains how SAS does the Y-W method of autoregression, compared to [this doc page](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/tsprais.pdf) that explains how Stata does it.

Second, you probably should not specify `method=YW`.  SAS distinguishes between the simple Y-W estimation ("two-step" method) and iterated Y-W estimation.  `method=ITYW` is what you want.  You specify `iter`, so it may well be that you're getting this anyway as SAS tends to be smart about those sorts of things, but it's good to verify.

I would suggest actually turning the iterations off to begin with - have both do the two-step method (Stata option `twostep`, SAS by removing the iter request and specifying `method=YW` or no method specification).  See how well they match there.  Once you can get those to match, then move on to iterated; it's possible SAS has a different cutoff than Stata and may well not iterate past that.

I'd also suggest trying this with only one independent and dependent variable pair first, as it's possible the two programs handle things differently when you add in a second independent variable.  Always start simple and then add complexity.